# Need to include strsafe.h after tchar.h Error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++

I'm trying to build application using Visual studio 2012 I'm getting following error while compiling

**C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\tchar.h(24): fatal error C1189: #error :  Need to include strsafe.h after tchar.h**

i included tchar.h after strsafe.h in stdafx.h file. still i'm getting same error . how to troubleshoot this problem

Comment: Reverse the order of inclusion? The error states that you should include `strsafe.h` _after_ `tchar.h`.

Comment: Move the #include for tchar.h *up* in the list of includes.  And do consider not including it at all, these tchar practices date from the previous century.  There is no version of Windows left that still needs it.  The floppy disk drive on the last machine that still boots a non-Unicode version of Windows died last week, problem solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Reverse the order of inclusion? **The error states that you should(*)
>   include `strsafe.h` after `tchar.h`.** –  Joachim Pileborg May 31 '13 at
>   8:25

(*) == **must**

> Move the #include for tchar.h up in the list of includes. And **do consider not including it at all, these tchar practices date from the
>   previous century.** There is no version of Windows left that still needs
>   it. The floppy disk drive on the last machine that still boots a
>   non-Unicode version of Windows died last week, problem solved. –  Hans
>   Passant May 31 '13 at 12:50

Answer (score 1):

Try adding #include  at the top of all headers

Answer (score 0):

Try adding #include  at the top of all headers. it Worked for me.
it is from the post 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/856e1cf6-d5bd-4e04-88eb-ea3aba3e8edc/why-getting-compile-error-need-to-include-strsafeh-after-tcharh?forum=vcgeneral